# How to filter an specific column inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, grid, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a grid with ng-repeat, like this:

**[RESOLVED]**:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xOTOsv

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar jogo" ng-model="gameCollection.name">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="game in colecao | filter:gameCollection" ng-if="$index%3==0">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="{{colecao[($index)].image}}" style="width:100%;" />
                        <p>{{colecao[($index)].name}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="{{colecao[($index+1)].image}}" style="width:100%;" />
                        <p>{{colecao[($index+1)].name}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="{{colecao[($index+2)].image}}" style="width:100%;" />
                        <p>{{colecao[($index+2)].name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I enter a value in the input Angular is filtering the entire row and not only the column.

Anyone know how to filter/delete only the column which matches the term?

Comment: why you don't change ng-if to <div class="col"> instead of <div class="row">?

Comment: The "ng-if" is just for having one row for each three columns. The problem is the filter is stripping the entire row and not the only column who match the input value. Thanks.

Comment: i don't see you apply any filter in the code you provided? or maybe you could provider a plnkr for it?

Comment: Here is: http://plnkr.co/edit/xOTOsv

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will filter only when the string entered is in "name" column

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="game in colecao | filter:gameCollection " ng-if="$index%3==0">
.
.
.
.
.

</div>
```

Comment: I forgot this filter part. You are right. But, even like that the filter erases all the row, not the only column who match the input sentence. Thanks for your help.